# check in view if validation passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to check in View if validation succeded (same as ModelState in Controler)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ModelState in view, this way:

```
<% if (this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) { %>
/* put your html here */
<% } %>
```